# The field 'field' doesn't exist - Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I have this class:

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

class ResCompany(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.company'

jour_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', string='Journal', required=False,
    help="Default journal for damaged invoices")
acc_id = fields.Many2one('account.account', string='Account', required=False,
    help="Default account used for invoices and lines from damaged invoices")
printer_fiscal = fields.Boolean(string='Manages fiscal printer',
    help='Indicates that the company can operate a fiscal printer')

@api.model
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    """ To create a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResCompany, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)

@api.multi
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):
    """ To write a new record,
    adds a Boolean field to true
    indicates that the partner is a company
    """
    context = dict(context or {})
    context.update({'create_company': True})
    return super(ResCompany, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values,
                                         context=context)
```

And this is the view of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record id="view_account_config_settings2" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account settings2</field>
        <field name="model">account.config.settings</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Configure Accounting" class="oe_form_configuration">
                 <separator string="Invoice Damaged" groups="account.group_account_user"/>
                    <group name="fr1_grp" string="Damaged Invoices Info">
                        <field name="jour_id"/>
                        <newline/>
                        <field name="acc_id" domain="[('type','in',('other','receivable','payable'))]"/>
                    </group>
                    <group name="fr2_grp" string="Does This Company Use Fiscal Printer?">
                        <field name="printer_fiscal"/>
                    </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

It throws me this error on view validation:

```
2017-02-28 18:48:17,540 6919 ERROR gilda_1 werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/server.py", line 246, in app
return self.app(e, s)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
result = handler(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__
return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 1454, in dispatch
odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/__init__.py", line 55, in registry
return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 55, in __new__
return cls.new(db_name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 78, in new
odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 333, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 235, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 177, in load_module_graph
env['ir.ui.view']._validate_module_views(module_name)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 1171, in _validate_module_views
self.raise_view_error("Can't validate view: %s" % e.message, vid)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_ui_view.py", line 445, in raise_view_error
raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Can't validate view: El campo `acc_id` no existe

Error de contexto:
Vista `account settings2`
[view_id: 895, xml_id:    l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements.view_account_config_settings2, model:  account.config.settings, parent_id: n/a]
```

It says that it can't validate the view because the field `acc_id` doesn't exists.

But it's there, even with the `string` flag which is mandatory on Odoo v10 community.

Can anybody point me what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `acc_id` is on the `res.company` model and the view you are creating has a

`<field name="model">account.config.settings</field>`

You either create that field on the `account.config.settings` model or change the model of the view